# Python failing to check if a value is in a list

Tags: python, mysql, discord.py

So I have this bit of code that selects every row in the column userID, puts the returned value in a dictionary then prints it.

```
whitelist = []            

with db.cursor() as cursor:
    whitelist_get = "SELECT userID FROM whitelist;"
    cursor.execute(whitelist_get)
    whitelist = str(cursor.fetchall())
    print(whitelist)
```

And this bit of code checks if the author ID from discord is in that whitelist list.

```
async def _function(ctx):
    global whitelist
    if ctx.message.author.id in whitelist:
        print("access granted")
    else:
        print("access not granted")
```

However, when running the script, the code goes over `global whitelist` then it does not procced in the `if` statement nor the `else` statement. It just does nothing. It doesn't print anything either. Am I doing anything wrong?

EDIT: My author ID is in the MySQL table and it should print `access granted` but it doesn't print anything at all.

EDIT2: Solved by chaning `if ctx.message.author.id in whitelist:` to `if str(ctx.message.author.id) in whitelist:`

Comment: Can you share a snipped showing also how you call the function?

Comment: @GPhilo hi, this is a discord bot command, so it just has ```@bot.command(name="function")``` before ```async def``` and the function gets called whenever I type the command "simi function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fetchall` method returns a sequence of tuples, so you should unpack the tuples to extract the first items first. For efficient lookups, you can make whitelist a set instead:

```
whitelist = {id for (id,) in cursor.fetchall()}
```

Comment: This was indeed an advancement, it now prints "access not granted", however my author ID is in the column "userID" and it should print "access granted"

Comment: @IonutSauciuc your first script turns `whitelist` in a string, you probably want to `whitelist.append` the result instead (or concatenate to the existing items, at least)

Comment: What data types are `ctx.message.author.id` and the column `userID`?

Comment: @GPhilo I tried appending and it still doesn't print anything.
@blhsing ```ctx.message.author.id``` is int and the ```userID``` column is VARCHAR.